# React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (I see no issues with imports/exports)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm creating a simple React website and my console keeps showing this error when I try to open the home page in the browser.

"Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

After looking at other questions from people who had the same issue, it seems they were lacking curly braces in the imports, but I believe I am doing that correctly. In fact, I cannot find anything wrong with my imports/exports. Any direction will be greatly appreciated! Also, I am using mapDispatch because I am also using Redux here.

My component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getCampuses, getStudents } from '../reducers';

import Nav from './Nav';
import Home from './Home';
import Students from './Students';
import Campuses from './Campuses';
import EditCampus from './EditCampus';
import EditStudent from './EditStudent';
import CreateStudent from './CreateStudent';
import CreateCampus from './CreateCampus';
import Student from './Student';
import Campus from './Campus';
import Footer from './Footer';

class Root extends React.Component{

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetch();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Nav />
          <div className='container-fluid'>
            <Switch>
              <Route path='/students/:id' component={ Student } />
              <Route path='/campuses/:id' component={ Campus } />
              <Route path='/editstudent/:id' component={ EditStudent } />
              <Route path='/editcampus/:id' component={ EditCampus } />
              <Route path='/createstudent' component={ CreateStudent } />
              <Route path='/createcampus' component= { CreateCampus } />
              <Route path='/students' component={ Students } />
              <Route path='/campuses' component={ Campuses } />
              <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
            </Switch>
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

const mapState = null;

const mapDispatch = dispatch => ({
  fetch() {
    dispatch(getCampuses());
    dispatch(getStudents());
  }
});

export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(Root);
```

Rendering the DOM:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import store from './store';
import Root from './components/Root';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Root />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('main')
)
```

Comment: For which component do you get this error? Are you sure you are exporting all your components you are using in your Root app?

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this you are using HashRouter which is used for the static website but in your case, it is not. So try this,

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Answer (score 0):

So when I changed to BrowserRouter I got a different error that said "Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _store.getCampuses) is not a function". I finally got it to work though when I imported the getCampuses function more specifically with '../reducers/campuses' (where I was exporting the getCampuses function). I did the same with getStudents ('../reducers/students'). Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!